# Azure Durable Functions - diagnose failures

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am testing how durable functions can fan in/out and how I can scale my code. for this example I am simulating many short running, cpu intensive operations.

Not all activities seem to complete and I am not sure why or where to look to find the log for failures.

Please see the code below:

```
public static class ParallelLoadDurable
    {
        [FunctionName("ParallelLoadDurable")]
        public static async Task<string> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            DateTime StartTimer = DateTime.Now;

            int counter = 0;
            var parallelTasks = new List<Task<string>>();
            var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(
                 firstRetryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                 maxNumberOfAttempts: 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                counter += 1;
                DurablePassModel DPM = new DurablePassModel()
                {
                    LoopNum = counter,
                    StartedOn = StartTimer
                };
                Task<string> task = context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync<string>("ParallelLoadDurable_Hello", retryOptions, DPM);
                parallelTasks.Add(task);
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);

            DateTime CompleteTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan TS = CompleteTime.Subtract(StartTimer);

            string ret = $"PROCESS COMPLETED: {counter} times for: {TS.TotalMilliseconds} ms.";
            log.LogInformation(ret);
            return ret;
        }

        [FunctionName("ParallelLoadDurable_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] DurablePassModel val, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Starting child function num {val.LoopNum.ToString()}.");
            DateTime StartTimer = DateTime.Now;

            var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);

            while (true)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now >= endTime)
                    break;
            }

            DateTime CompleteTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan TS = CompleteTime.Subtract(val.StartedOn);
            TimeSpan TSThis = CompleteTime.Subtract(StartTimer);

            string ret = $"Ran this for: {TSThis.TotalSeconds}s - LoopNum: {val.LoopNum} - total time: {TS.TotalSeconds}s.";
            log.LogInformation(ret);

            return ret;
        }

        [FunctionName("ParallelLoadDurable_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,
            [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("ParallelLoadDurable", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
```

What I get in almost every case is about 96% of the expected activities completed. this is from the results in the history table where EventType = TaskCompleted

Also in the "instances" table the RuntimeStatus just remains on "running"

Where could I look to find the list of failures?

Thanks for any help

Nick

Answer (score 1):

Surround your code with a `try` `catch` block and then log the exception using the `Ilogger`.

It can be achieved by like this

```
try
{
   //Do something
}
catch(Exception ex){
   log.LogError($"Error in function: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Then you can view the error messages in the logs or as well as `Application insights` if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you configure Application Insights for Azure Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring
Although there is some cost involved for the storage of the data it does help a lot when investigating issues.

In addition (or when you don't want Application Insights) you can query the status of the orchestration either via [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management#query-instances) or [HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#get-all-instances-status). This also works very nicely when you run & debug on your local machine!

Using the HTTP API you could do the following query to determine the failed instances:

```
@functionAppUrl = https://{{appName}}.azurewebsites.net
@code = YOUR_HOST_KEY
@taskHub = YOUR_HUB_NAME (see host.json)
@createdFrom = 2019-02-01T20:00:00Z

GET {{functionAppUrl}}/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances
        ?taskHub={{taskHub}}
        &code={{code}}
        &createdTimeFrom={{createdFrom}}
        &runtimeStatus=Failed
```

I noticed you're using `DateTime.Now` in your orchestration code. It is advised to use the `CurrentUtcDateTime` property from the `DurableOrchestrationContext` since the behavior in the orchestration function should be deterministic. See [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay#orchestrator-code-constraints) about orchestrator code constraints.